Unbiased estimate of success probability
Typically we assume independence to estimate the probability of success i.e. probability of head in a coin tossing example. Means we toss a coin $n$ times and see how many times we get heads, and the ratio is unbiased estimate of the probability of head.
However in real life case, these events are always not independent. For example, due to some environmental reason, if there is a head then there may be higher likelihood that next result will also be head.
So my question is will the sample ratio still be unbiased estimate of the success probability for such correlated case? Or, we need some correlation-adjustment to the sample ratio to get unbiased estimate of the success probability?
Any insight or book/online reference will be very helpful.

The first question is whether there even is a well-defined 'probability of a head' if environmental reasons mean that a head is more likely to be followed by another head.
However, suppose we pass that by and say our model is that every coin toss has unconditional probability $p$ of being a head, but with some correlation. In that setting, the sample ratio is still unbiased for the true $p$, because expectations always add, regardless of correlations.
Write $H_n=1$ if the $n$th coin toss is head and $H_n=0$ otherwise. Then
$$E\left[\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^NH_n\right]=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^NE\left[H_n\right]=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^Np=p$$
